# Disable/clear function when click in a side of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container with a video inside. When I click for the first time the video plays, and when I click for the second time the video pauses. I need to "clear" this event when I click on the left and on the right side of the div. Is that possible with a function like this?

This is my code for determining the left and right side of the div:

```
<div class="container">
  <video style="width: 100%"> </video>
</div>
```

```
$('.container').on('mousemove', function (event) {

        var viewportOffset = event.pageX / $ls(window).width();
        if (viewportOffset <= 0.4) {
            // video doesn't play or pause when click inside this range
        } else if (viewportOffset > 0.6) {
            // video doesn't play or pause when click inside this range
        } else {
           // Video play and pause when I click inside this center area
        }

    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt looks a little misguided to me, focus on capturing the click event itself and preventing the default action, like this

```
yourVideoElement.on('click', function (event) {
    var viewportOffset = event.pageX / $ls(window).width();
    if (viewportOffset <= 0.4) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (viewportOffset > 0.6) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

OR, with pure HTML/JS you can actually do it more simple by using the video element and its .play() and .pause() interface :), see below for brief example

```js
document.querySelector("video").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // HERE use e.x to calculate mouse position
    e.target.pause(); // this just always pauses now, never plays
})
```

```html
<video autobuffer controls autoplay style="width: 400px">
  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable any mouse (pointer) events with the following CSS rule.

```css
.container video {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

But checking for mouse positions over a video can be a bit cumbersome. I'd suggest you overlay a set of HTML elements, like buttons, and listen to the clicks on those controls.

Then whenever the user interacts with the video, like clicking on it, it has certain areas that could be clicked. See the example below.

```js
const video = document.querySelector('#video');
const controls = document.querySelectorAll('.container button');

controls.forEach(control => {
  control.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    
    switch(value) {
      case 'play':
        if (video.paused === true) {
          video.play().catch(console.log)
        } else {
          video.pause();
        }
        break;
      case 'prev':
        video.currentTime -= 0.5;
        break;
      case 'next':
        video.currentTime += 0.5;
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 3em 1fr 3em;
  width: 350px;
}

.container button {
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container .prev {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.container .prev:active {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .play {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.container .play:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container .next {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.container .next:active {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container video {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video id="video" width="350">
    <source src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  
  <button type="button" class="prev" value="prev"></button>
  <button type="button" class="play" value="play"></button>
  <button type="button" class="next" value="next"></button>
</div>
```

This would also solve your "removal of the event" problem as the user is not directly interacting with the video.